# How to unmute headphones by default when plugged into MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones

Each time the mac is turned on, and the headphones are plugged in, they are muted by default on my MacBook Pro. I need to unmute them **every time** in System Preference-> Sound -> Output. I have thus two questions:

1) Do you know any way to automatically unmute the headphones when plugged into the mac ? A terminal command or any other manipulation ?

2) Is the behavior of my Mac normal ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) 
You can use a third-party app like [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) or [EventScripts](https://www.mousedown.net/software/EventScripts.html) to trigger a volume setting script whenever you plug your headphone.

For exemple, with EventScript:

- Click on *Open Folder* from EventScripts menu in order to open the scripts folder.
- Add the script you want to be triggered, in your case something like `do shell script "osascript -e 'set volume 1'"` (note that set volume function works from 0 to 7, 0 being mute and 7 maximum volume).
- Click on *Choose Script* from EventScripts menu and select the script to be used.
- Add the event *Headphone connected*.

See my own setup as exemple to quit or launch *Boom* whenever my headphone or my bluetooth device is found:

[image]

2) I don't think this behavior is normal, your Mac should remenber the last volume setup you had with headphone... You should try to reset the PRAM setting, it may work :
shutdown your Mac and restart it while pressing and holding <kbd>option</kbd> +  <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>  + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>